# Read data from SQLite where column name contains spaces

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am having a coulmn name called "condition name" (.sql file has been generated from server)

But in android I am getting following exception while reading data from that table.

> 12-24 14:34:00.870: W/System.err(269):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: condition: ,

while compiling:

> SELECT condition, category, subcategory,condition name, local path,
>   remote path, title, content_type FROM library WHERE category = ?

Its not recognizing whole table name and breaking at space.
if you have any ideas please assist me.

Comment: For some reason I always find whitespace in names of things of this nature an irrational idea.

Comment: Try wrapping the table name in backticks, like in normal SQL

Comment: @JanDvorak you mean like [condition name] ?

Comment: @VijayYD These are square brackets. Backticks are the things that make StackOverflow think you want to format as an inline code block.

Comment: @JanDvorak can you please elaborate with simple example as i am new to sql . I have tried all possible ways suggested in several blogs but could not succeed.

Comment: @VijayYD what is your query?

Comment: @VijayYD what is your schema? Can you paste the CREATE statement?

Comment: database.query("library", new String[] { "condition","category",
      "subcategory","local path",
      "remote path","title"},
      null, null, null, null, null);

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html just do as described, and everything will be fine.

Comment: i have not created database tables, its been created in server and sending .sql file and i need to query the tables.

Comment: I can't see any `condition name` in the query.

Comment: @JanDvorak   
database.query("library", new String[] { "condition","category", "subcategory","condition name","local path", "remote path","title"}, null, null, null, null, null); ----- missed string but there are 2 more tables which contains spaces

Comment: @VijayYD would you mind me asking you to show us the schema for the table you are asking about or the query that refers to said table? `library` doesn't contain a space nor it seems to contain a column name with a space.

Comment: this is the query where library is table and "condition","category", "subcategory","condition name","local path", "remote path","title" are column names and its throwing error while reading values for condition name,local path,remote path

Comment: @JanDvorak sorry for misleading table name as its column name

Comment: put the column in quotes

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For quoting identifiers like table/column names, SQLite supports back ticks for compatibility with MySQL, and square brackets for compatibility with SQL Server, but the portable way is to use double quotes:

```
SELECT "condition name" FROM library
```

(Single quotes would be used for string values.)

Answer (score 7):

And you put the table name outside the quote as in:

tableName."column name"

and not

"tableName.column name"

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes

```
SELECT 'condition name' FROM library
```

or double quotes

```
SELECT "condition name" FROM library
```

---

in some cases the name of the table can contain space and even aphostrope, like:

```
SELECT condition's name FROM library
```

in this case replace `'` with `''` in the name of the table:

```
SELECT 'condition''s' name FROM library
```

Comment: Nope. `''` are strictly for string literals, while `""` are for quoting identifiers. Did you even try your examples? Given: `create table t(k integer primary key, "two words" text not null);insert into t values (1, 'text1'), (2, 'text2');` check `SELECT 'two words' FROM t;` vs `SELECT "two words" FROM t;`.

Answer (score -2):

```
String someName = "The pig";
String sql = 
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + COL_TITLE + "=" + '"' + someName + '"';
```

Comment: I think you'll need to explain what you are doing here to solve the problem.  It is not obvious what part fixes it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Sorry guys, that's some mistake!