# java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "Name": syntax error)

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I am doing a log in application in which users should be able to sign in. But I am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "Name": syntax error)
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
saveTButton.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, (e)-> {

        try
        {
            String query = "insert into TeachersInfo (First Name,Last Name,UserName,Password) values (?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = connectionUsers.prepareStatement(query);
            //First question mark = 1, second = 2, etc.
            pst.setString(1,nameSignupTTextField.getText());
            pst.setString(2,lastnameSignupTTextField.getText());
            pst.setString(3,usernameSignupTTextField.getText());
            pst.setString(4,passwordSignupTTextField.getText());


            pst.execute();

            System.out.println("Data saved");

            //after executing the query this lines will close the connection with the database
            pst.close();

        }
        catch(Exception a)
        {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    });
```

The code should save the info entered by the user in the database. I have no idea what is the problem so I would really appreciate the help. Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Since your column names contain spaces, you should escape them :

```
String query = "insert into TeachersInfo (\"First Name\",\"Last Name\",UserName,Password) values (?,?,?,?)";
```

See this topic : [Read data from sqlite where column name contains spaces in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019275/read-data-from-sqlite-where-column-name-contains-spaces-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if empty signs are allowed in table columns in sql lite. But you could try this:

```sql
insert into TeachersInfo ([First Name],[Last Name],UserName,Password) values (?,?,?,?)
```

Otherwise try to edit the column names.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the space in your column names `First Name` and `Last Name`. If those are really the column names, I guess you have to properly quote them. But it would be better not to use spaces in column names.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use space in column name.

```
       try
    {
        String query = "insert into TeachersInfo (First_Name,Last_Name,UserName,Password) values (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = connectionUsers.prepareStatement(query);
        //First question mark = 1, second = 2, etc.
        pst.setString(1,nameSignupTTextField.getText());
        pst.setString(2,lastnameSignupTTextField.getText());
        pst.setString(3,usernameSignupTTextField.getText());
        pst.setString(4,passwordSignupTTextField.getText());


        pst.execute();

        System.out.println("Data saved");

        //after executing the query this lines will close the connection with the database
        pst.close();

    }
    catch(Exception a)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
});
```